# Peewee ORM class definition for per-instance databases

Tags: python, peewee

I'd like to have different database files for each Peewee ORM instance. Peewee assigns the database engine to an instance using a nested "Meta" class.

My issue seems to come down to accessing a class instance attribute from an inner class. Using the Peewee quickstart example, this is what I'm trying to achieve in (broken) Python:

```
from peewee import *

class Person(Model):
    
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database
    
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    is_relative = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        
        # The following is incorrect; I'm trying to access the instance
        # variable for the database filename string
        database = SqliteDatabase(Person.database)

# Create two instances with different databases:
john = Person('john-database.db')
jane = Person('jane-database.db')
```

I've found a few general answers regarding nested classes, but struggle to translate their lessons to this specific application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the short answer is "peewee isn't really designed for your use case".  But I played around with it a bit, and while there has to be a better solution out there, here's something worked. But it's not a good idea, and you shouldn't do it.

First, we use the standard peewee example model, except we use the [Proxy](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database) class for the database connection:

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse import *

db = Proxy()


class Person(Model):

    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    is_relative = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

Assume we have this in `model.py`.

Now, to make this work, we're going to need two instances of the `model` module, which we can get by (ab)using the `importlib` module:

```
import importlib.util
import peewee
import sys

def load_module_as(modname, alias):
    mod_spec = importlib.util.find_spec(modname)
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(mod_spec)
    mod_spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
    sys.modules[alias] = mod
    return mod
```

This allows us to load in two separate instances of the `model`:

```
model1 = load_module_as('model', 'model1')
model2 = load_module_as('model', 'model2')
```

And we can then initialize two different databases:

```
model1.db.intitialize(pwee.SqliteDatabase('db1.db'))
model2.db.intitialize(pwee.SqliteDatabase('db2.db'))
```

While this sort of gets you what you want, you will always need to qualify your classes (`model1.Person`, `model2.Person`).

Here's a complete example, with unit tests:

```
import datetime
import importlib.util
import os
import peewee
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile
import unittest


def load_module_as(modname, alias):
    mod_spec = importlib.util.find_spec(modname)
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(mod_spec)
    mod_spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
    sys.modules[alias] = mod
    return mod

model1 = load_module_as('model', 'model1')
model2 = load_module_as('model', 'model2')


class TestDatabase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.workdir = tempfile.mkdtemp('testXXXXXX')
        self.db1_path = os.path.join(self.workdir, 'db1.db')
        self.db1 = peewee.SqliteDatabase(self.db1_path)
        self.db1.connect()

        self.db2_path = os.path.join(self.workdir, 'db2.db')
        self.db2 = peewee.SqliteDatabase(self.db2_path)
        self.db2.connect()

        model1.db.initialize(self.db1)
        model2.db.initialize(self.db2)

        self.db1.create_tables([model1.Person])
        self.db2.create_tables([model2.Person])

    def test_different_instances(self):
        assert model1.db != model2.db

    def test_create_model1_person(self):
        p = model1.Person(name='testperson',
                          birthday=datetime.datetime.now().date(),
                          is_relative=True)
        p.save()

    def test_create_model2_person(self):
        p = model2.Person(name='testperson',
                          birthday=datetime.datetime.now().date(),
                          is_relative=True)
        p.save()

    def test_create_both(self):
        p1 = model1.Person(name='testperson',
                           birthday=datetime.datetime.now().date(),
                           is_relative=True)
        p2 = model2.Person(name='testperson',
                           birthday=datetime.datetime.now().date(),
                           is_relative=False)
        p1.save()
        p2.save()

        p1 = model1.Person.select().where(model1.Person.name == 'testperson').get()
        p2 = model2.Person.select().where(model2.Person.name == 'testperson').get()

        assert p1.is_relative
        assert not p2.is_relative

    def tearDown(self):
        self.db1.close()
        self.db2.close()
        shutil.rmtree(self.workdir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the thorough answer! I'll give this a try.

Comment: Since I didn't need to access both databases simultaneously, it was as simple as using the Proxy object as you pointed out in your first example. Thank you!